How to Trigger Cloud Functions from Firebase Extension Events for Cloud SQL Integration?
I’m using a Firebase extension for resizing images and I have a Cloud Function that should be triggered after the resizing process is completed. The goal is for this function to generate download links for the new images and write them to a Cloud SQL database.
Here’s what I’ve encountered:
• Using Firebase Functions: While they can handle Firebase extension triggers, I’m unable to add a Cloud SQL connection in the Cloud Run part.
• Using Plain Cloud Functions: These can connect to Cloud SQL, but I can’t configure them to be triggered by Firebase extension triggers.
In theory, the setup should work, but I’m stuck at this configuration issue. Is there a way to configure a Cloud Function to be triggered by custom Eventarc events from a Firebase extension?
Any guidance or suggestions on how to fix this configuration would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
